# CallEventhandler not invoked in objective c

Tags: iphone

i have to get call status on the end of the call but my event is not invoked following like line always return false

[callCenter setCallEventHandler: ^(CTCall* call)

here is my code

```
CTCallCenter *callCenter = [[CTCallCenter alloc] init];
callCenter.callEventHandler=^(CTCall* call)
{

    if(call.callState == CTCallStateDialing)
    {
        //The call state, before connection is established, when the user initiates the call.
        NSLog(@"Call is dailing");
    }
    if(call.callState == CTCallStateIncoming)
    {
        //The call state, before connection is established, when a call is incoming but not yet answered by the user.
        NSLog(@"Call is Coming");
    }

    if(call.callState == CTCallStateConnected)
    {
        //The call state when the call is fully established for all parties involved.
        NSLog(@"Call Connected");
    }   

    if(call.callState == CTCallStateDisconnected)
    {
        //The call state Ended.
        NSLog(@"Call Ended");
    }

};
```

any help will be greatly appriciated

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks good; however, your event handler will not be invoked if your app is suspended during the call event.

Source: [CTCallCenter Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Reference/CTCallCenter/Reference/Reference.html)

> If your application is active when a call event takes place, the
>   system dispatches the event to your handler immediately. However, call
>   events can also take place while your application is suspended. While
>   it is suspended, your application does not receive call events. When
>   your application resumes the active state, it receives a single call
>   event for each call that changed state—no matter how many state
>   changes the call experienced while your application was suspended. The
>   single call event sent to your handler, upon your application
>   returning to the active state, describes the call’s state at that
>   time.