# iOS telprompt - can you get the status of the call?

Tags: ios, phone-call, telprompt

The app I'm working on makes calls when the user tells it to, using telprompt to come back to the app when the call is over. Is there any way to tell what caused the call to end? If the call failed, I'd like to do one thing, but if it succeeded and the user just hit "END" I want to do something else. I'm not seeing anything in the documentation about it, though.

TIA

Janene

Comment: A question that I would like to have answered as well!

Comment: check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12642471/calleventhandler-not-invoked-in-objective-c